# unity3d: Adding half-transparent video with shadows

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, transparency, shadow, alpha-transparency

I'm struggling with an issue that might seem a little bit awkward.
I have some black & white 2d animation (1440x1080px) that I'd like to be played in in a 3d environment in unity3d. Therefor I added a video player to a plane. Now comes the tricky part: I want to make the black areas of the video transparent while the white areas remain visible AND the white areas shall cast shadows on the surrounding. Using the particles shader "additive" does half of the job. But I just can't manage to let the video cast a shadow.

If it worked you would get some 2d "antagonist" (you can't interact with) that looks kind of 3d. Alternatively you could interprete it as some half materialzed holograph that casts shadows.

Is there any (simple) solution I just don't know?

Here some [schematic drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvKnn.jpg) of what I would like to achieve, for better understanding.

The problem right now is: In contrast to my drawing, the desired shadow on the wall doesn't appear... :-/

Comment: You just described two things you want to do without a single code. I suggest you separate this into two questions. This question for the transparency goal and create another question foe your shadow goal. Also add what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Actually there isn't that much of code to post. Since I'm a noob in unity, I was searching the internet for an answer to my problem. I there found some selfmade shader scripts that I tried, but without success. Making the video transparent now really is not a problem. As described using the particles shader "additive" does the transparency thing. The problem is that for me it seems like it's incompatible with shadow casting. I tried lots of stuff I found online without success. Now I don't have a clue what to do, that's why I'm here... :-/

Answer (score 0):

So, I did never try this but you can maybe add a light in the scene just in front of the video player, that way the light will cast shadows.

Comment: Thanks for your comment :-)
Unfortunately it seems like I have not managed to describe my problem very well. Adding a light actually is not the problem. The problem is that the video won't cast a shadow...
I'll try to add a picture to clarify my problem ^^'